# icon font stuck between 2 div

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs inside, each having 2 spans. 1 of the span is the insert the icon font and the other containing text. Only the first div has the icon. Somehow the span containing the icon font would overlap the other div as shown[image]:

My code for the divs and spans are as follow:

HTML

```
<div class="delivery-container"> <span class="glyphicons nav-icons heart delivery-logo"></span>

    <!-- <h1 class="services-brand">Services We Provide</h1> --> <span class="delivery-desc ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</span>

</div>

<div class="payroll-container">
    <div class="payroll-logo"></div> <span class="payroll-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</span>

</div>

<div class="it-container">
    <div class="it-logo"></div> <span class="it-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</span></div>
</div>

.glyphicons.nav-icons:before {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 .4em;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    font: 72px/2em 'Glyphicons Regular';
}

div.delivery-container, div.payroll-container, div.it-container {
    width:100%;
    padding: 2em 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

span.delivery-logo {
    float:left;
}
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance!

http://jsfiddle.net/Gdv7A/

Comment: try `.glyphicons.nav-icons:before { display: inline-block;...`

Comment: didn't change anything. do ask if you need more information. thanks though!

Comment: right click icon, inspect it on developer toolbar and change the css properties there. Without a demo its hard to help. It looks here http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/rgEV7/

Comment: i'm sorry that i cannot do a demo since the icon fonts is on a font file and i would have to upload both the font file and the css. I really appreciate your help though (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your full code, try placing a `overflow: hidden` on your .delivery-container element.

If you could maybe show the rest of your code or create a jsfiddle.

But after what I can see, the div that holds your icon is maybe set to a static height or you icon has a position on it.

Comment: somehow overflow:hidden did it for me. anybody mind explaining why it worked? Instead of hiding part of the icon font, the div actually expands. Thanks a lot.

Comment: And to explain why: By using overflow: hidden, the element will get a new block format that collapses all the margins the child element has. You can read all about this on: [link](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/)